# Not a version: 9 exception with Scala 2.11.12

Tags: scala, apache-spark, debugging, java-8, spark2

The Scala application with Scala 2.11.12 is throwing following error while executing certain set of code

The environment configurations are as follow:

```
Scala IDE with Eclipse: version 4.7
Eclipse Version: 2019-06 (4.12.0)
Spark Version: 2.4.4
Java Version: "1.8.0_221"
```

However the same set of configuration is working fine in eclipse IDE with Scala version 2.11.11

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: Not a version: 9
    at scala.util.PropertiesTrait$class.parts$1(Properties.scala:184)
    at scala.util.PropertiesTrait$class.isJavaAtLeast(Properties.scala:187)
    at scala.util.Properties$.isJavaAtLeast(Properties.scala:17)
    at scala.tools.util.PathResolverBase$Calculated$.javaBootClasspath(PathResolver.scala:276)
    at scala.tools.util.PathResolverBase$Calculated$.basis(PathResolver.scala:283)
    at scala.tools.util.PathResolverBase$Calculated$.containers$lzycompute(PathResolver.scala:293)
    at scala.tools.util.PathResolverBase$Calculated$.containers(PathResolver.scala:293)
    at scala.tools.util.PathResolverBase.containers(PathResolver.scala:309)
    at scala.tools.util.PathResolver.computeResult(PathResolver.scala:341)
    at scala.tools.util.PathResolver.computeResult(PathResolver.scala:332)
    at scala.tools.util.PathResolverBase.result(PathResolver.scala:314)
    at scala.tools.nsc.backend.JavaPlatform$class.classPath(JavaPlatform.scala:28)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPlatform.classPath(Global.scala:115)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global.scala$tools$nsc$Global$$recursiveClassPath(Global.scala:131)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global.classPath(Global.scala:128)
    at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.BTypesFromSymbols.<init>(BTypesFromSymbols.scala:39)
    at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.BCodeIdiomatic.<init>(BCodeIdiomatic.scala:24)
    at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.BCodeHelpers.<init>(BCodeHelpers.scala:23)
    at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.BCodeSkelBuilder.<init>(BCodeSkelBuilder.scala:25)
    at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.BCodeBodyBuilder.<init>(BCodeBodyBuilder.scala:25)
    at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.BCodeSyncAndTry.<init>(BCodeSyncAndTry.scala:21)
    at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenBCode.<init>(GenBCode.scala:47)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$genBCode$.<init>(Global.scala:675)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global.genBCode$lzycompute(Global.scala:671)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global.genBCode(Global.scala:671)
    at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenASM$JPlainBuilder.serialVUID(GenASM.scala:1240)
    at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenASM$JPlainBuilder.genClass(GenASM.scala:1329)
    at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenASM$AsmPhase.emitFor$1(GenASM.scala:198)
    at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenASM$AsmPhase.run(GenASM.scala:204)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnitsInternal(Global.scala:1528)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnits(Global.scala:1513)
    at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$ToolBoxGlobal.wrapInPackageAndCompile(ToolBoxFactory.scala:197)
    at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$ToolBoxGlobal.compile(ToolBoxFactory.scala:252)
    at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$$anonfun$compile$2.apply(ToolBoxFactory.scala:429)
    at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$$anonfun$compile$2.apply(ToolBoxFactory.scala:422)
    at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$withCompilerApi$.liftedTree2$1(ToolBoxFactory.scala:355)
    at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$withCompilerApi$.apply(ToolBoxFactory.scala:355)
    at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl.compile(ToolBoxFactory.scala:422)
    at com.slb.itdataplatform.dq.DataQualityValidation$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(DataQualityValidation.scala:112)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at com.slb.itdataplatform.dq.DataQualityValidation$.compile(DataQualityValidation.scala:109)
    at com.slb.itdataplatform.dq.DataQualityValidation$.generateVerifier(DataQualityValidation.scala:104)
    at com.slb.itdataplatform.dq.DataQualityValidation$.main(DataQualityValidation.scala:49)
    at com.slb.itdataplatform.dq.DataQualityValidation.main(DataQualityValidation.scala)
```

I can work on the same set of environment configuration but `Spark 2.4.4` underlined `Scala version is 2.11.12` hence I want to use the same in my application to avoid any conflicts.(As my spark apps are not initializing [Unable to initialize Spark job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57790353/unable-to-initialize-spark-job))

What could be the possible root cause for this error and how it can be resolved?

Comment: Are you sure you are running on Java 8?

Comment: @Thilo - Yes, the environment details are correct.

Comment: looks like this set of code is creating problem `def checkSrcCode(checkCodeMethod: String, id: Int): String =
      s"""com.amazon.deequ.checks.Check(com.amazon.deequ.checks.CheckLevel.Error, "$id")$checkCodeMethod"""` . However the same is working fine with Scala 2.11.11

Comment: It might be a doc. bug, but Spark says "Spark 2.4.4 uses Scala 2.12. You will need to use a compatible Scala version (2.12.x)." in its documentation (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/)

Comment: @mazaneicha - Yes, it seems a bug. Spark documentation suggesting to use 2.12.x with spark 2.4.4, however the bundled underlined Scala version is 2.11.12